# Acentos mail PHP

Tags: php

Tengo un formulario creado en HTML, PHP y Ajax. Lo unico que no puedo realizar es que al momento de que me envíe los datos del formulario de contacto en PHP. Los acentos no me los muestra correctamente, no se como lograr que al momento de enviarme los datos del formulario a mi correo electrónico estos acentos se muestren correctamente. Les proporciono mi parte del código en PHP. El mail me llega correctamente, nada más son los acentos. Si me pudieran apoyar se los agradecería.

Gracias

```js
if (empty($_POST["nombre"])){
   $error = 'Ingresa un nombre <br/>';
}else{
    $nombre = $_POST ["nombre"];
    $nombre = filter_var($nombre, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
}

if (empty($_POST["email"])){
   $error .= 'Ingresa un e-mail <br/>';
}else{
   $email = $_POST["email"];
   if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
      $error .= 'Ingresa un E-mail verdadero';
   }else{
      $email = filter_var($email,FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
   }
}

if (empty($_POST["motivo"])){
   $error = 'Ingresa un asunto <br/>';
}else{
    $motivo = $_POST ["motivo"];
    $motivo = filter_var($motivo, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
}

if (empty($_POST["mensaje"])){
   $error .= 'Ingresa un mensaje <br/>';
}else{
    $mensaje = $_POST ["mensaje"];
    $mensaje = filter_var($mensaje, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
}

$cuerpo .= "Nombre: ";
$cuerpo .= $nombre;
$cuerpo .= "\n";

$cuerpo .= "Email: ";
$cuerpo .= $email;
$cuerpo .= "\n";

$cuerpo .= "Asunto: ";
$cuerpo .= $motivo;
$cuerpo .= "\n";

$cuerpo .= "Mensaje: ";
$cuerpo .= $mensaje;
$cuerpo .= "\n";

$enviarA = 'empresa@empresa.com'; //CORREO ELECTRÓNICO
$asunto = 'Empresa';

if($error == ''){
$success = mail ($enviarA,$asunto, $cuerpo, 'de: '.$email);
echo 'exito';
}else{
   echo $error;
}

?>
```

Comment: Ya lo intente pero no se como queda.

Comment: Disculpa, pero no entiendo. ¿Que fue lo que intentaste y no sabes como queda?

Comment: Lo que me mandaste en el artículo, no se donde queda o como programarlo en mi código. Nada más tengo ese error, en los acentos que no se muestran bien cuando me llega el mail.

Answer (score 0):

Puede que tenga que ver con la codificación de los caracteres, lo puedes intentarlo aplicándole utf8 con la funcion utf8_decode() o con utf8_encode()

Ejemplo:

```
if($error == ''){
  $success = mail ($enviarA,$asunto, utf8_decode($cuerpo), 'de: '.$email);
  echo 'exito';
}else{
   echo $error;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por su ayuda ya quedo solucionado.

Comment: @FernandoLopez favor de marcar si te fue útil la respuesta,  te invito a visitar [¿Por qué es importante votar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)